# Tizen - Does samsung AV player support .m3u playlist format?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, television, tizen-web-app

Recently, In my tizen web app, I have been playing with **.m3u8** format video files and it works perfectly in **samsung AV player**. (http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/avplay-api)

But when it comes to **.m3u** playlist format, it does not automatically detects the video in there. Do i need to configure anything in here? Am i missing something?

Not sure how to make the .m3u fomat work in this player. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the solution. Actually av player has .m3u format support, **but it will not work in simulator**. We need to test it in real TV device to play the contents of .m3u format.

And also don't forget to set the **required privilege** for the application to get the video from outside world in config.xml file.

Thanks

Comment: is it worked for anyone? as i am not having device/TV i need to arrange.